# How do I paste html into a textbox?

Tags: html, copy-paste

I want a user to highlight a part of a web page and paste it into a textbox on my site.  But I want the formatting from the original site to be preserved somehow.  So I want to copy more than just text.  Gmail seems to be able to do this when composing an email.

I don't know where to begin with this problem.  Any thoughts?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Perl. All client-side, HTML and probably custom Windows browser abilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you have windows7 use the snipping tool and cut it from the screen as a .jpg.

Then use simple html

```
<img src="sth.jpg" alt="sth" height="" width="">
```

Comment: He wants HTML, not JPG